# Get Rendering React Target/DIV

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Is it possible to access the parent node of a react element in which it is rendered in?

Example:

```
<div id='some-app'></div>
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('some-app'))
```

In React Component

```
[...] extends React.component {
  constructor(props) {
    console.log('I have been rendered into ' + pseudoGetIdOfParentDiv())
    // outputs: 'I have been rendered into some-app'
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)` after the component has been mounted (i.e. in the `componentDidMount()` function) to get the root node of your component. You can then access its `parentNode` attribute.

```
let node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
let parentNode = node.parentNode;
```

Only do this after the component has been mounted - otherwise `findDOMNode(this)` will return null.

Info on `componentDidMount()` can be found here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount and `findDOMNode()` here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode